# Display Advanced Custom Fields data under thumbnails in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up an advanced custom field to display on the backend of my product pages using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  I am using this to create a button that pops up a PDF preview of each of my products.  I would like this to appear under the product image/thumbnails. The name of the field is product_preview.

For the life of me I cannot find a tutorial on how to make this field appear on the front end of each product page.  Basically I will update that field with the new PDF link.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to put the code in the template override (theme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php).

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to do code.  I was hoping for a little hand holding.  :) What code do I need to put?

Comment: `<?php the_field('field_name')?>` replace `field_name` with the name of the field you set in ACF.